# SimpleData casting objects with ALL_CAPS and underscores

Tags: oracle, simple.data

I'm not sure if anyone else has run into this, but I am having a heck of a problem when trying to cast returns from an Oracle database that has column names in ALL_CAPS with underscores.  I am trying to figure out a code way to get it done, but it looks like the cast calls aren't homogenizing.  Here is a quick example:

```
MY_TABLE { COLUMN, COLUMN_ONE, COLUMN_TWO } = {{"a", "b", "c"}}
```

When mapping to

```
public class MyClass 
{ 
     public string Column { get; set; }
     public string Column1 { get; set; }
     public string Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Will only map Column, and ignore mapping Column1 and Column2.

Thanks in advance for any input and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my bad.  The issue was a hidden conversion error (there was trouble converting from the decimal? that the databse was sending to the int? the class expected), and a string to GUID conversion error.